# Does a CPU cache entry contains physical or virtual address?

Tags: x86-64, memory-address, virtual-memory, cpu-cache

Does a CPU cache deal with physical or virtual addresses? And if it deals with virtual addresses, does that mean that it has be to emptied on context switch, assuming that the new thread is from another process.

Comment: It does not need to be emptied (if dealing with virtual addresses) on thread switches, just its entries become stale and will be eventually overwritten and reused. BTW, your question is only hardware dependent (and has nothing to do with `C`, `Linux`, or `gcc` ....)

Answer (score 2):

This depends on the processor model. [Some processors use both.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache#Virtual_tags_and_vhints) (See “SPARC” in the “Virtual tags and vhints” section.)

You have tagged this question with x86-64, and an answer could be given for all x86-64 models to date, but I am not sure whether the architecture specification specifies whether processors conforming to the specification must use one or the other for cache information.

Comment: I don't think x86-64 has a mechanism to let the OS know it would have to use page-coloring to avoid synonym aliasing for a VIPT cache, or to flush on context switch for a VIVT cache.  If not, that would mean all caches have to give the illusion of caching based on physical address only, avoiding any kind of aliasing.  So I think all caches have to give the illusion of working like PIPT.

Comment: Fun fact: the decoded-uop cache in Sandybridge-family *is* virtually addressed.  I'm not sure if it gets transparently invalidated on changing the page tables.  It's small enough and the legacy decoders are good enough that it would be fine.